# Giving "Cannot read property 'password' of undefined" instead of handling the error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to build a user login system using express js and dynamodb, but the issue is whenever I'm trying to login a user using correct email or password, it works fine, but if I'm using any wrong email, it's not able to handle the error. It's giving me some error like cannot find password of undefined.
Can someone please tell me how to handle with this error and why this error?
I tried some [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902166/typeerror-cannot-read-property-password-of-undefined-in-login-route/55902240) similar to mine, but that actually does not solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

This is my whole `userLogin` file:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();

AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-2" });

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  user_type = "employee";
  const email = req.body.email;
  docClient.get(
    {
      TableName: "users",
      Key: {
        user_type,
        email,
      },
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send("Invalid username or password");
      } else {
        if (data && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data.Item.password)) {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              email: data.Item.email,
            },
            process.env.SECRET,
            { expiresIn: "1d" }
          );
          res.status(200).send({ user: data.Item.email, token: token });
          next();
        } else {
          res.status(400).send("Password is wrong");
        }
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```js
I:\somePath\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

Error [TypeError]: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
```

Comment: Print out the values of request.body and data.Item.  compare what you see against what you expect to see

Comment: For a valid email: req.body is returning the body obj I'm passing and data.Item is returning the whole user obj.

Comment: For an invalid email: req.body returning the the body obj I'm passing and data.Item os returning undefined, and that's the error says, "Cannot read property password of undefined, where the password is coming from the data.Item

Comment: What do you expect DynamoDB to return if you ask it for an undefined email?  In other words, what do you expect the value of data.Item.password to be in that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something to catch when data doesn't return valid data. If you could post what the data object looks like, that would help.

```
(err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    res.send("Invalid username or password");
  } else {
    // Add data.Item check
    if (data && data.Item && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data.Item.password)) {
      const token = jwt.sign({
          email: data.Item.email,
        },
        process.env.SECRET, {
          expiresIn: "1d"
        }
      );
      res.status(200).send({
        user: data.Item.email,
        token: token
      });
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(400).send("Password is wrong");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate, what code should I change or write?

Comment: `bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.Item.password, (err, user) => {`

Comment: Your data variable appears to be an array. You create the `user` variable but don't use it, I would think a password property would be in user(`data[0]`).

Comment: The user variable is unnecessary, I tried that code from some stackoverflow code. I've updated my original code. Can You check it again?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to have a more robust snippet